# Reading intricated dictionaries in depth Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a big dictionary with smaller dictionaries inside, and i'm trying to get the values inside that aren't dictionaries (but strings, lists or integers), with their "path". I tried to use DFS (Depth First Search) techniques, but without success. Here is a sample of my big dictionary :

```
{
    'visPlaneSection':
    {
        'ValueMode': 'Single Section',
        'OriginInput': '[0.4, 1.3877787807814457E-17, -8.4350929019372245E-16] m,m,m',
        'OrientationInput': '[1.0, 0.0, -3.3133218391157016E-16] m,m,m',
        'CoordinateSystem': 'Laboratory->Reference',
        'InputPartsInput': '[Region]',
        'ValueIndex': '-1',
        'visSingleValue':
        {
            'ValueQuantityInput': '0.0 m'
        }
    },
    'ChildrenCount': '2'
}
```

The data i need is : visPlaneSection.ValueMode = 'Single Section'

- visPlaneSection.ValueMode = 'Single Section'
- visPlaneSection.OriginInput = [0.4, 1.3877787807814457E-17, -8.4350929019372245E-16] m,m,m
- ...ect...
- visPlaneSection.visSingleValue.ValueQuantityInput = '0.0 m'
  How should i do that ? It might be a tree discovery in depth issue, but i don't know how to implement that on my problem.

[EDIT] : To be more specific, here's what I have today :
    `def test(dictio, path=[]):
        print(path)
        if type(dictio) == dict:
            for k in dictio.keys():
                if path == []:
                    path.append(k)
                else:
                    new_path = path[-1] + "." + k
                    path.append(new_path)
                test(dictio[k], path)
        else:
            path.pop()`

So, with the dictionary i showed you, the final element of each lists is the path i want, but it is not working perfectly :
    `[]
    ['visPlaneSection']
    ['visPlaneSection', 'visPlaneSection.ValueMode']
    ['visPlaneSection', 'visPlaneSection.OriginInput']
    ['visPlaneSection', 'visPlaneSection.OrientationInput']
    ['visPlaneSection', 'visPlaneSection.CoordinateSystem']
    ['visPlaneSection', 'visPlaneSection.InputPartsInput']
    ['visPlaneSection', 'visPlaneSection.ValueIndex']
    ['visPlaneSection', 'visPlaneSection.visSingleValue']
    ['visPlaneSection', 'visPlaneSection.visSingleValue',     'visPlaneSection.visSingleValue.ValueQuantityInput']
    ['visPlaneSection', 'visPlaneSection.visSingleValue',     'visPlaneSection.visSingleValue.ChildrenCount']`

We have here `visPlaneSection.visSingleValue.ChildrenCount` instead of `visPlaneSection.ChildrenCount` for the last element, that's where my issue is.
Thanks for your patience and answers

Comment: e.g. single_section = d['visPlaneSection']['ValueMode']

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404665/accessing-elements-of-python-dictionary

Comment: Well, i see how i can get a specific value, but i have troubles reading all my dictionary (with a recursive algorithm) and get the path of each data.

Comment: What is the final form that you want? An object?

Comment: @RedX I need the value and the path as two different objects (str for the path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention the python version you're using to do this, python 3.4+ would look much better with `yield from` syntax and whatnot. Here's what a came up with for python 2.7:

```
def deconstruct(node, path=None):
    if not path:
        path = []

    for key, value in node.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            for sub_value in deconstruct(value, path + [key]):
                yield sub_value
        else:
            yield (value, '.'.join(path + [key]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for value, path in deconstruct(input_dict):
        print path, '=', value
```

If execution speed is your concern - you might want to replace the list with string in path variable.

Comment: but `ChildrenCount` doesn't belong to `visPlaneSection` dict, why would it show that?

Comment: Yeah, i just saw that, that's my mistake :) Your code is great, thank you again !

Answer (score -1):

What do you need to do with the data? If you just want to print it, you need something like this:

```
def _print_dict(s,d):
    for k,v in d.iteritems():
        dot = "." if s else ""
        p="{}{}{}".format(s,dot,k)
        if isinstance(v,dict):            
            _print_dict(p,v)
        else:
            print "{} = {}".format(p,str(v))
```

and then:

```
_print_dict('',d)
```

Comment: That's pretty close to what i'm searching for, but i need the path (your 's') to fit each data. Here, i have with your program : visPlaneSection.ValueMode.OriginInput.OrientationInput.CoordinateSystem.InputPartsInput.ValueIndex.visSingleValue.ValueQuantityInput. = 0.0 m
Or i need visPlaneSection.visSingleValue.ValueQuantityInput = '0.0 m'

Comment: @M.Charlélie , you're right, fixed the code now