# Python, taking specific data from JSON

Tags: python, json

I'm playing around with the league of legends api, anyway I made this very simple program.

```
import requests
region = input("Enter a region ")
summonerName = input("Enter Summoner Name ")
apikey = input("Enter APIKey ")
r = requests.get(url="https://" + region + ".api.pvp.net/api/lol/" + region + "/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" + summonerName + "?api_key=" + apikey)
print(r.json())
```

and this is what it returns.

```
{'hiimeric': {'revisionDate': 1478543641000, 'name': 'Hi Im Eric', 'id': 36843151, 'profileIconId': 13, 'summonerLevel': 30}}
```

so my question is now, how could I for example get it to only post 'name' or only 'name' and 'profileIconId'? Thanks!

Comment: Are you assuming that the value `'hiimeric' is known or unknown to you? (The answers so far assume that it is known.) Are you sure that values for only one user will be returned?

Comment: It's just a dictionary, containing another dictionary. Perhaps you wanted to [read the tutorial on dictionary use](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing elements of python dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404665/accessing-elements-of-python-dictionary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JSON object is actually just a combination of dictionaries and lists. Hence, you can print the name and profileIconId with the following:

```
print(r.json()['hiimeric']['name'])
print(r.json()['hiimeric']['profileIconId'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Json objects are two kinds: `dict` and `list`. In this case, it is `dictionary`. If you want to know explicit, use `type` function like this.

```
obj = r.json()
print(type(obj))
```