# Python Dictionary Access Via Keyword (TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str)

Tags: python, google-maps, dictionary

I am attempting to select the distance from a googlemaps query. The data seems to have returned via a dictionary. However, I am not able to access the information I need.

What I am looking at

```
{'copyrights': 'Map data ©2017 Google', 'warnings': [], 'summary': 'NJ Tpke 
S and I-95 S', 'legs': [{'traffic_speed_entry': [], 'distance': {'value': 
365542, 'text': '227 mi'},
```

What I want returned "227 mi".

What I have tried is below

```
>>> dirs[0]['summary']
'NJ Tpke S and I-95 S'
>>> dirs[0]['summary'][0]['traffic_speed_entry'][0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#117>", line 1, in <module>
    dirs[0]['summary'][0]['traffic_speed_entry'][0]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I tried the approaches in these references, too:

[accessing-elements-of-python-dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404665/accessing-elements-of-python-dictionary) and
[inverse-dictionary-lookup-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568673/inverse-dictionary-lookup-in-python)

I also imported into pandas, numpy, and tried to slice it.

Here's the code that creates the dictionary:

```
>>> import googlemaps
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='APIKEY')
>>> start = '07042'
>>> end = '20024'
>>> dirs = gmaps.directions(start, end)
```

Does Google do something funny when they return a dictionary?

Comment: >>> dirs[0]['text']Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#120>", line 1, in <module>
    dirs[0]['text']
KeyError: 'text' @JuanT

Comment: For the `traffic_speed_` error you can try `dirs[0]['legs'][0]['traffic_speed_entry']`

Comment: @polonius11 I meant `dirs[0]['legs'][0]['distance']['text']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"traffic_speed_entry" is in the "legs" field, not the "summary".  Let's take your attempt, one subscript at a time:

```
dirs[0]
```

I assume that this is the item you posted in the first code box.

```
dirs[0]['summary']
```

As you've noted already, this is the string 'NJ Tpke S and I-95 S'.

```
dirs[0]['summary'][0]
```

This is the letter 'N' at the start of that string.

```
dirs[0]['summary'][0]['traffic_speed_entry']
```

This is equivalent to

```
'N'['traffic_speed_entry']
```

You're trying to index one string with another.

SOLUTION

You need to access the field properly.

```
dirs[0]['legs'][0]['distance']['text']
```

I recommend that you try adding a single element at a time, checking that you got what you expected:

```
>>> dirs = [ {'copyrights': 'Map data 2017 Google', 'warnings': [],
              'summary': 'NJ Tpke S and I-95 S',
              'legs': [{'traffic_speed_entry': [], 
                        'distance': {'value':365542, 
                                     'text': '227 mi'}}]},
             "other dictionaries"  ]
>>> dirs[0]
{'legs': [{'traffic_speed_entry': [], 
     'distance': {'text': '227 mi', 'value': 365542}}], 
     'summary': 'NJ Tpke S and I-95 S', 
     'copyrights': 'Map data 2017 Google', 'warnings': []}
>>> dirs[0]['summary']
'NJ Tpke S and I-95 S'
>>> dirs[0]['summary'][0]
'N'
>>> dirs[0]['legs']
[{'traffic_speed_entry': [], 
  'distance': {'text': '227 mi', 'value': 365542}}]
>>> dirs[0]['legs'][0]
{'traffic_speed_entry': [], 
 'distance': {'text': '227 mi', 'value': 365542}}
>>> dirs[0]['legs'][0]['distance']
{'text': '227 mi', 'value': 365542}
>>> dirs[0]['legs'][0]['distance']['text']
'227 mi'
```

Answer (score 1):

`dirs[0]['legs'][0]['distance']['text']` should work.

---

It means, that from the `dict` in `dirs[0]`,  select the element with key `'legs'`, which is a list.

Extract the zeroth element of that `list` and find the key `'distance'` from that element (which is a `dict`).

In that last element find `'text'`, and return the corresponding string.

---

**Note that:** you were trying to access `traffic_speed_entry` which does not contain the information you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The *miles* you are looking for should be in

```
dirs[0]['legs'][0]['distance']['text']
```

Note that you have a list (in `legs`) within a dictionary that contains another dictionary!

EDIT, based on comment:

> How do I read a list within a dictionary which contains another dictionary?

You just kinda pile on call onto the other one. See also the accepted answer above. Note that a `list` is indexed by position, e.g. `legs[0]` indicates the first item in `legs` ([tutorial on lists](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm)). This item happens to be a dictionary in oyr case (it could have been anything, really). This dictionary, different from a list, can be accessed through its keys, as you did above ([tutorial on dicts](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html)). Here, we want what's stored under the key `distance`. Alternatively, we could have pulled the key `traffic_speed_entry` out.

> That is clearly what confused me. The distance, text is the list? Legs & dirs are the dictionary?

Note that lists are indicated by `[` and `]` in Python, dictionaries by `{` and `}`. Lists are lists of things (e.g. `[1,'aaa']`), while dictionaries associate keys with values (e.g. `{key1:1, key2:'aaa'}`). Try reading your example with that in mind.

You can assemble your example like so:

1. `dirs` is presumably a list; we use `[0]` to extract its first item.
2. This item is a dictionary (we know that because in the example you posted it is in `{`. we extract the value associated with the key `legs` by calling `['legs']`. This value happens to be a list.
3. Just like above, we access the first item in that list through `[0]`. Etc.

Comment: How do I read a list within a dictionary which contains another dictionary? That is clearly what confused me. The distance, text is the list? Legs & dirs are the dictionary?

Comment: @polonius11 added detail above