# Accessing a list contained in a JSON object with Python

Tags: python, json

```
testVar = {
  "date": 1520053431,
  "location": {
  "lat": 39.349887,
  "lng": -82.116147
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "macAddress": "98:90:96:9C:94:6C",
      "manufacturer": "intel"
    },
    {
  "macAddress": "98:90:96:9C:94:52",
  "manufacturer": "intel"
    },
    {
      "macAddress": "98:90:96:90:94:52",
      "manufacturer": "intel"
    }
  ]
}

print(testVar.items[0])
```

I have this JSON object, and I'm trying to access the items list, but this produces the error:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

I tried parsing it with json.loads and json.dumps but neither of those worked either.

Comment: Unlike JavaScript, Python differentiates between hashtable accesses (i.e. dictionaries) and object field access. You can't use the dot operator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing elements of python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404665/accessing-elements-of-python-dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it has curly brackets (`{...}`), it's stored in a `dict`(ionary). This means you can't use the dot operator (`.`) to access the data inside.

As it's a `dict`, you also can't access it like a `list`. Instead, you need to use the keys available (the strings before the colons).

In this case, you need to do something like `textVar['items']` to access the `'items'` `list`.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce No, it's always good to have detailed answers which explain the problem to the OP.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce it's not identical, it has an explanation. Which means it should have been a comment on your answer reminding you to include it, but meh.

Comment: @Adi219 It's probably worth pointing out that the exact error message given is because there **is** in fact an [attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) `items` on the dictionary, but that it isn't the same as the *member* called `'items'`.

Answer (score 12):

Let me present a very simple example first, since this is going to be very useful for us later on. Imagine I have this simple function:

```
def myFunc():
    return [1,2,3]
```

Question: What is the first element of `myFunc`? In other terms, what is `myFunc[0]`. Be careful, I am not asking the first element of the output of it, i.e. `myFunc()[0]`; my question is the first element of `myFunc` itself! The former would be the first element of `[1,2,3]`, which is `1`; but the latter will give me a `TypeError`, because a function can't be subscripted; akin to the fact that a recipe can produce delicious food, but you can't eat the recipe itself.

Let's take a look at your error message:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

This means that you are somehow trying to subscript a 'builtin_function_or_method' object. Let's look at your code and understand what this error is due to. Luckily, your call is just one line, hence easy to debug:

```
testVar.items[0]
```

What you are doing is to reach the first element of the `items` function or method of a `dict`. Be careful, not the first element of the outcome, but the function itself. How am I so sure? Because you forgot the parentheses, therefore haven't even called the function yet, i.e. you didn't do `testVar.items()[0]`.

Let's look closer at the built-in `items` function of `dict`s. When we just run `testVar.items`, this is the response we get: `<function items>`. Let's run the following to get some help about its docstring: `?testVar.items`, which returns the following:

```
Docstring: D.items() -> list of D's (key, value) pairs, as 2-tuples
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```

A-ha! We just saw what the error message we had mentioned: `builtin_function_or_method`! So the error is really due to your code not being able to call the function properly, but try to get the first element of the function itself.

Let me give a simpler but equivalent example. Say, I have a list `x = [2, 3, 1]` and I want to find its smallest element. I can use the built-in function of `sort`, and then get the first element in the sorted list. Therefore the proper syntax would be `x.sort()[0]` but if I forget the `()`, and write `x.sort[0]` I will be trying to get the first element of not the result of the `sort` function (because I didn't even call it to get a result!) but the first element of the function itself. Remember the recipe not being edible? Same thing.

**In summary: A function can return an iterable which you can subscript, but a function itself is not subscriptable.**

Let's play around with this function a little bit. Let's iterate on it as (key, value) pairs per docstring:

```
for k, v in testVar.items():
    print k, v
# Result:
date 1520053431
items [{'macAddress': '98:90:96:9C:94:6C', 'manufacturer': 'intel'}, {'macAddress': '98:90:96:9C:94:52', 'manufacturer': 'intel'}, {'macAddress': '98:90:96:90:94:52', 'manufacturer': 'intel'}]
location {'lat': 39.349887, 'lng': -82.116147}
```

This makes sense, because we indeed have 3 keys and corresponding 3 values.

**Now, how can you get the values corresponding to the key named `items`? Notice, this is one of your three keys, but has the same name as the built-in function of `dict`s we discussed above. This is where your confusion is coming from.**

The error message was due to the `items` function, let's discuss how to get the value corresponding to the key named `items`. One inefficient way is using the loop syntax I presented above:

```
for k, v in testVar.items():
    if k == 'items':
        print v
# Result:
[{'macAddress': '98:90:96:9C:94:6C', 'manufacturer': 'intel'}, {'macAddress': '98:90:96:9C:94:52', 'manufacturer': 'intel'}, {'macAddress': '98:90:96:90:94:52', 'manufacturer': 'intel'}]
```

There you go, here is your `items`! A second and efficient way of doing the same thing is calling the key name, and the values will be returned to us:

```
testVar['items']
# Result: 
[{'macAddress': '98:90:96:9C:94:6C', 'manufacturer': 'intel'},
 {'macAddress': '98:90:96:9C:94:52', 'manufacturer': 'intel'},
 {'macAddress': '98:90:96:90:94:52', 'manufacturer': 'intel'}]
```

### To wrap-up:

1. Pay attention to the cases where your `key` in a `dict` has the same name of a built-in function or method.
2. You can't do `myDict.key`, but `myDict['key']`.
3. You can also loop over the `item` function of `dict`s as `(key, value)` pairs and get the value corresponding to the key. But don't do this, this is inefficient compared to the constant time complexity of `myDict['key']`.
4. If you are calling `myDict.function`, make sure you actually put that function into action by `myDict.function()`. That is, don't eat the recipe, but eat what it produces.

Answer (score 2):

testVar is a dictionary and dictionaries in Python have the *items()* method. For instance, in order to access all key/value pairs in this dictionary, you would use, according to [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques). Notice the `items()` method below.

```
for key, value in testVar.items():
      print(key, value)
```

As pointed out by @FatihAkici, the statement `testVar.items()[0]` is syntactically incorrect in that you are trying to call the `items()` method which does not support indexing. This means that you cannot access items within the object by index positions, like we do in lists:

Accessing a list by index position:

```
music = ['Beatles', 'Led Zeppelin', 'The Doors']
#item at index 0:
music[0]   #Beatles
```

Meanwhile, as you can see the object `testVar.items()` is of type `dict_items` and can only be accessed by key/value.

```
testVar.items()[0]
TypeError: 'dict_items' object does not support indexing

#Output: dict_items([('date', 1520053431), ('location', {'lat': 39.349887, 'lng': -82.116147}), ('items', [{'macAddress': '98:90:96:9C:94:6C', 'manufacturer': 'intel'}, {'macAddress': '98:90:96:9C:94:52', 'manufacturer': 'intel'}, {'macAddress': '98:90:96:90:94:52', 'manufacturer': 'intel'}])])

print(testVar.items())
```

To access the `items` list, you can use list comprehensions. This is a compact way to access all items with less code:

```
test = [print(key, value) in testVar for key,value in testVar.items() if key=="items"]

#test: items [{'macAddress': '98:90:96:9C:94:6C', 'manufacturer': 'intel'}, {'macAddress': '98:90:96:9C:94:52', 'manufacturer': 'intel'}, {'macAddress': '98:90:96:90:94:52', 'manufacturer': 'intel'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the print statement. **JSON** works as same as a dictionary.
so to access any element in dictionary, we use **dictionary_name[key]**

Therefore the below code works fine:

(change the print statement in the code as below)

```
print(testVar['items'][0])
```

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Just because you've posted an answer, it doesn't mean others can't.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the wanted variable by doing this:

```
print(testVar["items"][0])
```

Because both "testVar" and "items" are dict variables.