# How to access certain values of a json site via python

Tags: python, json, request, python-requests

This is the code i have so far:

```
import json
import requests
import time

endpoint = "https://www.deadstock.ca/collections/new-arrivals/products/nike- 
air-max-1-cool-grey.json"
req = requests.get(endpoint)
reqJson = json.loads(req.text)

for id in reqJson['product']:
    name = (id['title'])
    print (name)
```

Feel free to visit the link, I'm trying to grab all the `"id"` value and print them out. They will be used later to send to my discord.

I tried with my above code but i have no idea how to actually get those values. I don't know which variable to use in the `for in reqjson` statement

If anyone could help me out and guide me to get all of the ids to print that would be awesome.

```
for product in reqJson['product']['title']:
    ProductTitle = product['title']
    print (title)
```

Comment: Just access the `dict` values.... take a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404665/accessing-elements-of-python-dictionary

Comment: what would i put in the `for _ in reqjson[__]` though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see from the link you provided that the only `id`s that are in a list are actually part of the `variants` list under `product`. All the other `id`s are not part of a list and have therefore no need to iterate over. Here's an excerpt of the data for clarity:

```
{
    "product":{
        "id":232418213909,
        "title":"Nike Air Max 1 \/ Cool Grey",
        ...
        "variants":[
            {
                "id":3136193822741,
                "product_id":232418213909,
                "title":"8",
                ...
            },
            {
                "id":3136193855509,
                "product_id":232418213909,
                "title":"8.5",
                ...
            },
            {
                "id":3136193789973,
                "product_id":232418213909,
                "title":"9",
                ...
            },
            ...
       ],
        "image":{
            "id":3773678190677,
            "product_id":232418213909,
            "position":1,
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

So what you need to do should be to iterate over the list of `variants` under `product` instead:

```
import json
import requests

endpoint = "https://www.deadstock.ca/collections/new-arrivals/products/nike-air-max-1-cool-grey.json"
req = requests.get(endpoint)
reqJson = json.loads(req.text)

for product in reqJson['product']['variants']:
    print(product['id'], product['title'])
```

This outputs:

```
3136193822741 8
3136193855509 8.5
3136193789973 9
3136193757205 9.5
3136193724437 10
3136193691669 10.5
3136193658901 11
3136193626133 12
3136193593365 13
```

And if you simply want the product id and product name, they would be `reqJson['product']['id']` and `reqJson['product']['title']`, respectively.

Comment: wow no way. I was so close to this when i was changing the code up. Could you explain to me why you put `for product in reqJson['product']['variants']:` please? I have no clue why the product and variants are used. Just want a better understanding so i dont have to ask again lol

Comment: No problem. I've updated my answer with better explanations.

Comment: That makes alot more sense, now if i were to only access the product name, how would i do so because it isnt under the variants? Do i just use product?

Comment: The product name would be `reqJson['product']['title']`. I've updated my answer to include this note.

Comment: I edited my post to show what i have done, im getting "TypeError: string indices must be integers" so, not sure if i have done what you have explained.

Comment: You are trying iterate over `product`, which is only a dict, not a list. If you want the product names of the variants, you should iterate through `reqJson['product']['variants']`. I've updated my answer to show you the product (variant) names as well.

Comment: OHHH i was meaning the actual product title, `"title":"Nike Air Max 1 \/ Cool Grey"` its right at the beginning of the json and doesnt fall under the variants.

Comment: Yup. No need to use a loop if all you want is the product title. By the way can you mark this answer as accepted if you think it is correct?