# How to extract parameters from a list in a dictionary into separate columns as floats?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am having difficulty in extracting values from a dictionary. The dictionary includes a list that contains a pair of numerical values that are of interest and my intention is to extract them and save them in a separate csv file.

The dictionary array looks like this:

```
{"geodesic":false, "type":"Point", "coordinates":[34.5 , 23.5]}
```

I am trying to get the coordinates in two separate columns. Thank you!

```
pd.DataFrame(mydict).to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
dataset1 = pd.read_csv('out.csv')
dataset2 = pd.DataFrame(dataset1, columns=["coordinates"])
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is `cord_list = mydict["coordinates"]`.

You don't need to save it to a CSV and re-read it. You can access the variable directly from the dictionary. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404665/accessing-elements-of-python-dictionary-by-index) for more examples.

FYI, `pd.DataFrame(dataset1, columns=["coordinates"])` is not correct code. The `columns` field allows you to rename columns for display purposes, it won't change how many columns are actually loaded. The current code will just load all columns again.