# How do I print a specific string out of a dictionary element?

Tags: python, dictionary, ncbi

SOLVED: Its a a key in a dictionary embedded as an element in a list

```
print(read[0]["Title"])
```

[Heres a picture of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkrKW.png) I am trying to print the article titles (end of line 2) from this esummary request. However, I am unfamiliar with dictionary lists.

I have tried splitting and slicing but those are for elements and strings. I have also looked at [Accessing elements of Python dictionary by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404665/accessing-elements-of-python-dictionary-by-index) to no avail.
Here's some code...

```
titles = Entrez.esummary(db="Pubmed", id= "31106594, 30889179")

read = Entrez.read(titles)

print(read["Title"])
```

I want it to print "Development of a Molecularly Stable Gene Therapy Vector for the Treatment of RPGR-associated X-linked Retinitis Pigmentosa"

Instead it says "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: `read` is a list, not a dictionary

Comment: The error says that your 'print(read["Title"])' should have an integer instead of the string 'Title'

Comment: Thanks, when I've tried slicing, I can only do 0 and 1: one for each ID. Within each ID is a title, which is all I want. When I just print read it says DictElement at the beginning, which is why I thought it was a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a a key in a dictionary embedded as an element in a list

```
for i in range(len(read)):
    print(read[i]["Title"])
```