# Problems with dictionaries in python

Tags: python

```
translator = input("Enter a japanese word: ")

japanese_to_english = {
    "Konichiwa": "Hello",
    "baka": "fool",
    "gomen": "sorry",
    "sugoi": "awesome",
}
```

from the code given above, when the user types a word which is inside the dictionary.. I want it to replace the words.. it there any short way of doing this .. Please let me know... Thank you!

Comment: What do yo mean by replace the word? You want to replace the `key` or `value`. Where is the code that you had tried?

Comment: Idk how to do it so ya.. when I say replace I mean..if I type baka in the terminal it should show up as fool

Comment: Does my answer answers your problem ? Or it is something else ?

Comment: @Preciousツ my code helps in multiple words

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing elements of Python dictionary by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404665/accessing-elements-of-python-dictionary-by-index)

Comment: @Joshua Varghese yea thank you for your help! I really appreciate the fact that you helped me out but since I just started ... I dont get the code so...ya.. Thank you for helping tho! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a value from a key, the notation is `mydict[mykey]` or `mydict.get(mykey)`

```
translator = input("Enter a japanese word: ")

japanese_to_english = {...}

english_word = japanese_to_english[translator]       # raise error if word not in dict
english_word = japanese_to_english.get("translator") # return None if word not in dict
```

Comment: @Preciousツ You may leanr more python before trying to use it, because this is very basic of dictionnaries ;) You can think about vote up/accept the answer now ;)

Comment: yea..just started to learn for fun because of the whole situation rn...still learing...thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
translated = ' '.join(japanese_to_english[i] if i in japanese_to_english else i for i in translator.split())
```

Here, we split the input by space, checks them if they are inside the dict, if so replaces it. If not found the word is not replaced.
So if you input:

```
Konichiwa i am gomen
```

you get:

```
'Hello i am sorry'
```

Comment: An answer without details values nothing, you can't just tell the OP "Do this" without explaining how it solves its problem and what it does

Comment: I did not downvote, maybe the problem was that the OP did not talked about multiples words, don't know