# Export only a part of a request - python request

Tags: python, get

I have an GET api that returns

> file_url

and several other variables. I want to only export

> file_url

and just dump other variables.

```
import requests
response = requests.get("foo.xyz/index.php?example=example")
print(response.content)
```

but i only get an output of "illegible" full response.

```
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><posts  count="3893" offset="0"><post height="4089" core="0"file_url="https://foo.xyz/example.jpg"
```

[Program finished]

Comment: Please read [ask] and then update your question to show an actual example. But I suspect you're just trying to figure out how to [access part of a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5404665/354577)?

Comment: I want to request something from an GET api and use only one "variable" (in this case file_url). I could find a way to get an entire response but i can't manage to find an option to only print this one "variable" @Chris

Comment: @Cheis updated???

Comment: That looks like XML, but it isn't well-formed. Don't the `post` and `posts` elements close?

Comment: They close but i just anonimized the thing.