# why can't I use '.' to access my dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a game in python and am organizing my data.

```py
game={
    'img':{
        'bg':'wouir'
    }
}
print(stuff.img.bg)
```

When I push build it has an error on the last line saying:
`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'img'`

It seems I have a problem, what is it?

Comment: Python is not Javascript, dictionary keys are not attributes, and accessing with square brackets like `game['img']` is not interchangeable with dot notation like `game.img`.

Comment: "It seems I have a problem, what is it?" Well, in your own words, what does `attribute` mean in a Python program? *According to the sources you used to learn Python*, how is data retrieved from a dictionary?

Comment: [Accessing elements of Python dictionary by index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5404665/15497888)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access object's items through dot-notation in Python. You're supposed to use braces.

```py
screen.draw(game["img"]["bg"], (0,0))
```

Comment: I had used this before but didn't know this was the use case.
This is very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

In Python, the keys of a dictionary are **not** its attributes. This means you cannot call them with the `.`. You have to use `['img']` instead of `.img`.

Change your loop to this:

```
while True:
    screen.draw(game['img']['bg'], (0,0))    # I've only corrected game.img.bg
```